# How Do I Show a Dialog in Flutter Using a go_router Route?

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router, flutter-dialog

I am currently using [showGeneralDialog](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/showGeneralDialog.html) to present a dialog popup like this:

[image]

This is all fine and good, but it happens at the root `Navigator` level, and I would rather have all my views as a [Go Router](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router) route so that I can control their presentation in the same way throughout my app.

How can I use something like `showGeneralDialog` upon calling a route?

```
GoRoute(
  path: '/settings',
  pageBuilder: (context, state) {
    return ???;
  },
),
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Had the same question, found https://croxx5f.hashnode.dev/adding-modal-routes-to-your-gorouter which works well enough for me. Extended its builder by wrapping it in a `Dialog`.

This is what it looks like for me in the end:

```dart
// dialogpage.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DialogPage<T> extends Page<T> {
  final Offset? anchorPoint;
  final Color? barrierColor;
  final bool barrierDismissible;
  final String? barrierLabel;
  final bool useSafeArea;
  final CapturedThemes? themes;
  final WidgetBuilder builder;

  const DialogPage({
    required this.builder,
    this.anchorPoint,
    this.barrierColor = Colors.black87,
    this.barrierDismissible = true,
    this.barrierLabel,
    this.useSafeArea = true,
    this.themes,
    super.key,
    super.name,
    super.arguments,
    super.restorationId,
  });

  @override
  Route<T> createRoute(BuildContext context) => DialogRoute<T>(
        context: context,
        settings: this,
        builder: (context) => Dialog(
          child: builder(context),
        ),
        anchorPoint: anchorPoint,
        barrierColor: barrierColor,
        barrierDismissible: barrierDismissible,
        barrierLabel: barrierLabel,
        useSafeArea: useSafeArea,
        themes: themes,
      );
}
```

and used like this:

```dart
  GoRoute(
    name: 'bug-report',
    path: '/bug_report',
    pageBuilder: (context, state) => DialogPage(
      builder: (_) => BugReportPage(imagePath: state.queryParams['screenshot']),
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: Wow. After looking for a while, I ended up founding the same article. And now I just found this, when I was looking for a way to add transition animation in my dialogue. Any of you have any ideas?!?

Comment: Yeah, we have [this for a sidesheet transitioning in from the right](https://github.com/acterglobal/a3/blob/81f07466c9f98fcd65f667a2eb4aae4dc75fb597/app/lib/router/router.dart#L134-L156) (can't past, too long for a comment here).

Comment: @gnunicorn Thanks for sharing. Your solution is even cooler as it allows to define the transition type and its duration.

Comment: Does this also work for more complex route trees?
i.e. What happens if the dialog is shown from a subpage/subroute? On which page will the dialog be shown?